# Cheap repair of hole in car paint

Tags: repair, citroen

Recently my car paint has been damaged, I suspect it got hit by a little stone and the paint bursted. The bursts is not very nice but is very hard to notice because they are just about 3 cm long and very narrow. However, at the end a hole of about 1cm by 2mm has formed.

The hole is not big but really stands out because it exposes the white plastic bumper underneat. I am aware that I could probably bring it to a garage for a spot repair, but the minimum quote for that is about 150 euro so I will not be doing that. Especially as I expect to get rid of the car in one or two months. Hence my question:

## What is the best I can do to disguise this hole on a shoestring budget?

I am thinking of max 25 euro/dollar for something that makes my car look decent when I visit people, It is a black citroen and so far the best I came up with is just grabbing a permanent marker to make the underlying plastic black.

Answer (score 6):

Your local auto parts store should have touch-up pens. It's just a matter of finding a decent match.

Comment: You can also order them online.

Comment: Collision / Auto Body shops should also have a good selection of touch-up paint.